# Who do I talk to to buy a house in Falkreath?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Who do I need to talk to to purchase a house in Falkreath?  Is there one even available there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You *can* buy a house in Falkreath, but **only if you have Hearthfire**. In vanilla Skyrim, houses are only available in:

- Windhelm
- Whiterun
- Markarth
- Riften
- Solitude

This leaves Falkreath, Dawnstar, Morthal, and Winterhold without houses. The Hearthfire addon allows you to build houses in 3 of these areas - Dawnstar, Morthal, and Falkreath, leaving only Winterhold without a house you can buy.

Comment: Awww, would have been the perfect place for my wood elf.  Thanks, Mark!

Comment: That's stupid, Falkreath is my favorite of the skyrim towns. It is beautiful like Riverwood. Who would want to live in Windhelm instead? Markarth I suppose will be where I live then, as its the least capable of getting burned by Dragons.

Comment: @Slayer Not much of a Nord if you think Windhelm isn't located in a beautiful area of the country.

Comment: note that these are also the only cities that have a loading screen when you enter the city.

Comment: Too bad, I think Falkreath is my favorite too. Or maybe Riverwood. They remind me of trips to the cabin when I was a kid.